# Getting big number instead of infinity

Tags: python, math, sympy

I have a task to plot grafic of function with asymptotes using Sympy, Numpy and Pyplot. My function is `f(x) = (x^3 + 3 * x^2 - 2 * x - 2) / (2 - 3 * x^2)`. I found that vertical asymptotes are in `x = -sqrt(6)/3` and `x = sqrt(6)/3`, that means that `f(sqrt(6)/3) = oo`. But `F(-np.sqrt(6)/3)` returns `2451449131743593.0`, not infinity. Why? Also, MatLab gives me the same result, but `f(-np.sqrt(6)/3) = oo * sqrt(6) = 2451449131743593`.

Comment: Because floating point math.  `sqrt(6)/3` is an irrational number.  It can't be represented, in binary OR decimal.  Even without binary getting in the way, the result is always going to be an approximation.  The more math you do with that value, the more rounding errors you introduce.

Comment: [See more about floats](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21895756/why-are-floating-point-numbers-inaccurate#:~:text=Because%20often%2Dtimes%2C%20they%20are,many%20digits%20in%20any%20base.)

Comment: SymPy can represent the number `sqrt(6)/3` exactly so if you use sympy then `f(sqrt(6)/3)` gives `zoo` (complex infinity).